# ExpressJS - Port is not released after node application shuts down

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I noticed something rather peculiar when I was playing around with ExpressJS.

I am trying to close all db connections if the application is being shut down. 
But I noticed that even after the application is shut down, port 8080 is not released. I would have to manually find the id of the process holding the port and kill it.

It is obvious that I am either not letting go of the db connection or there is some kind of connection leak. But I am not sure what is actually causing the problem.

My code - 
index.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    db = require('./db'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Commenting out this portion of the code makes the problem go away.
// But I would Like to keep it so I can close all open database connections 
// before the application is closed

process.on('SIGINT',function(){
     console.log('Closing database pool');
     db.pool.end();
});

routes(app);
app.listen(port);
console.log(`API Server started on localhost:${port}`);
```

db.js

```
const config = require('./config'),
mysql = require('mysql');

exports.pool = mysql.createPool(config.mysql);
```

DB used is MySQL hosted on AWS RDS

Key Problems:

1. Port is not released even after application is closed.
2. Is there a connection leak etc? Should I be doing something more to handle my database connections more efficiently?
3. Is there a better way to process a scenario where the application crashes or is otherwise closed and process all open connections and failing safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
// assign result of listen()
const server = app.listen(port);

// then in your SIGINT handler do this
server.close()
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! But I would also like to know why this worked and what I was doing wrong. Would you be able to point me to resources where I can read up more on that please?

Comment: If you're overwriting handler for SIGINT I guess to need to take care yourself of shutting down your connections. `server.close()` actually has a callback, but don't know how to wait for it in the handler. You could also just try instead of `server.close` a `process.exit(0)`. Also the order with `db.pool.end()` could matter, don't know what's happening there exactly. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback